# PHP - I have 2 equivalent variables but only one works - Indirect vs Direct Variable?

Tags: php, html, variables

this may seem like a complicated question but this is just an example to help my understanding.

```
$valu2 = $_POST['selln'];
$valu3 = substr($valu2, 11);
$fin = $valu3;
if(array_key_exists('selln',$_POST)){
$result = randmFunction($user_id, $fin, 'usd');
}
```

Using the example above, why wouldn't randmFunction run with $fin when $fin = $valu3. ($valu3 = 1 so $fin = 1). When I would try code along this line the function won't run, but, if I change the code to:

```
$fin = 1;
if(array_key_exists('selln',$_POST)){
$result = randmFunction($user_id, $fin, 'usd');
}
```

The function runs fine. When I echo $fin they are the exact same, no spaces or anything. What is the difference? Why does only the exact value of 1 work?

Comment: not sure what randmFunction does but what if $fin must be an integer and you're providing it a string on first example? (just to make a test, try if randmFunction($user_id, (int)$fin, 'usd') works)

Comment: You're welcome @Codly72 but think about making a more accurate string validation because just casting data to int when calling randmFunction may give you unexpected behaviours if $_POST['selln'] string is not properly validated

Answer (score 0):

```
$valu2 = $_POST['selln'];
$valu3 = substr($valu2, 11);
$fin = $valu3;
if(array_key_exists('selln',$_POST)){
$result = randmFunction($user_id, $fin, 'usd');
}

function runs but $fin value is false;

Question:What is the testing value for $_POST['selln'];

Please give more details in the question
```